# Error in installing Windows XP on my Compaq Presario CQ62

Tags: windows-7, installation, bsod

i am not able to install windows xp on compaq cq62-105tu laptop,blue screen appears 
while trying to install xp  on my Windows 7   compaq cq62-105tu laptop.
Please help me

Comment: Are you trying to create a dual boot environment or replace Windows 7?

Comment: i m trying to  replace Windows 7 to windows XP

Comment: are you sure you're not just looking at the first screens of the XP installer?  you might need to provide more information about the trouble.  what does the bluescreen say?

Answer (score 1):

The most likely reason for this is an incompatibility in the BIOS. Unless your using XP with at least SP2 it won't recognise the drive if it's SATA, without an additional driver.

If the version of XP you're using does not have SP2 or SP3 slipstreamed, I'd check the settings in the BIOS and see if there is an option to set the drive type to IDE. Also check for AHCI settings and set those to IDE.

Personally, if you just want to remove Windows 7 and install XP, download [GParted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/) burn it to a CD or USB, boot from the CD/USB, repartition the notebook and install XP.

Comment: I don't think that it is the SATA issue...it wouldn't bluescreen but rather not find the HD. Though, it could still be somekind of incompatibility.

Comment: One would hope it would behave so sensibly, unfortunately, it's a well documented problem. Still, I'll wait to see what version of XP we are dealing with :)